# Copy / Paste + condition MAC

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have some columns in sheet 2.

I want that if in the Sheet2.Column C = "LIVE"
Then copy the Sheet2.Column B value in the Sheet1.Column E (and delete the space between value).

But I Don't know how to translate it in MAC VBA or why it doesn't work.

this is my code :

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim numero As String
Dim endcolumn As String

numero = 1
endcolumn = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
While numero <= endcolumn
    If Range("C", numero) = "LIVE" Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range(E, numero) = Sheets("Sheet2").Range(B, numero)
    End If

    numero = numero + 1

Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim numero As LONG Dim endcolumn As LONG`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare you vars as long; they are numbers, not strings. I've also corrected your range definitions and given Range("C", numero) a parent worksheet reference.

```
Sub Macro2()

    Dim numero As long
    Dim endrow As long

    numero = 1
    endrow = workSheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    While numero <= endrow 
        If workSheets("Sheet2").cells(numero, "C") = "LIVE" Then
            workSheets("Sheet1").cells(rows.count, "E").end(xlup).offset(1, 0) = _
                workSheets("Sheet2").cells(numero, "B").value
        End If

        numero = numero + 1

    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, everything is working well. Now I will need to understand to learn more. Again thank you.

Comment: And do you have the traduction for : Range("D3:D200").Clear for Mac ?

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that there are many differences in coding for VBA in MAC. In fact there are very few. Just use `Range("D3:D200").Clear` preferably with a valid parent worksheet reference.

Comment: That's odd. Not having a mac in front of me, I checked the questions in [tag:excel-vba-mac] and others don't seem to have a problem.